# Trouble with parallax scrolling

Tags: html, css, nav, parallax

So I have [this website](http://www.shonnyboymushi.com/inspiration.html) in the works and the header image uses a parallax plugin. How can I make the nav bar with the links "Inspiration," "My Work," etc...move with the header image as you scroll down. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Sorry, I'm new to writing code for websites and yes I am using weebly and it can be terrible but it'll have to do. I am able to upload javascript files and link to them through CSS and HTML)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use css. `position: fixed`. It would be more easier to help you if you posted your  code.

Answer (score 0):

add the following like of code to your css file in the header's styling section.

```
position: fixed
```

or check this tutorial for a complete tutorial

http://www.cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/

Regards

Shiva